# How to calculate t-values for deviation from chance & df?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have run an experiment for my dissertation and tested my participants. The test consisted of two sections, and each section consisted of two types of questions. It was a replication and in the image below you can see one of the tables displayed in the original article. The original study also split the Type A questions in two, but I have no intend to do so.

[image]

My question is how can I calculate the t-value (t-values for deviation from chance, as labeled in the article) and generate a table as above? When I try to reproduce the scores and calculate it using Excel, it does not give me the same results as above. I have found several guides on Google about how to calculate it, but none of them give me the results I want.

Thanks all.

Comment: I do not see sufficient information here to answer. For one troublesome test, please show specific hypothesis and alternative (hypothetical value and whether one- or two-sided alternative), along with sample size, mean, and SD. Show what P-value you're getting and why you think (or know) it is incorrect.